# SIP registration getting failed with request time out Samsung S6

Tags: android, pjsip

My Voip  application based on PJSIP stack. It is getting register to server for all the devices except Samsung galaxy S6. 
The error it is showing is  pjsua_core.c  .TX 562 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=17006 (tdta0x7f97121000) to…

For rest of the devices it is working fine
Any Suggestions

Thanks in Advance.

Thank you.

Comment: Request packets are not sent to the Server.It is working fine with all the devices. Any Suggestions please. Do we need to check any device settings?

Comment: please post full sip message response

Answer (score 0):

I believe the S6 doesn't support it. I've been having problems myself, by calling the isVoipSupported() method you get a false back.